# DiscordJS how to detect inhuman commands

Tags: automation, discord.js, bots, captcha, detection

I'm working on a Discord bot which handles a multiplayer game with rpg elements - those rpg elements allow users to perform different income activities in specified interval (best example would be EPIC RPG).

Considering the game is multiplayer and pretty much only interval based, I want to prevent players from using any automation, which allows them to take the top ranks with minimum effort and keep the game fair!

I'm currently running it in a small test server and already had a guy using something what allowed him to send those commands each 10 seconds (EDIT: from his personal user account), resulting in over 5000 commands within 16 hours. He's very mysterious about details of whatever he's using to achieve this outcome. I also found out he can even set multiple intervals at once which countered the solution I tried and will describe next.

**What I tried**
Implementing a captcha which randomly generates when user sends the command and temporary ban when user fails to complete the captcha - This is only a partial solution because he can still use the automation while doing other work arround and pass captcha when it pops
Implementing bonus captcha which generates when user sends the command in same interval twice in row - This only works if there is one timer, setting more timers counters this

So my question which is by now pretty much obvious I'd say is: How can I detect automation (interval patterns?) on those commands to effectively annoy those botters with captcha till they rather give up and play manually?

I'll be very grateful for any ideas and suggestions! <3

PS: I'm suprised he's getting away with that for weeks and months - sending 5000 messages a day, even tho not daily I believe. Isn't that API abuse violating Discord's ToS?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy question to answer.
The answer is:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

let prefix = "!";

client.on('ready', () => {console.log('I am Ready')});

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

  var args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
  var commands = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === "ping") {
    return message.channel.send('Pong!');
  }
})

client.login('INSERT TOKEN HERE');
```

So the if statement at the start of code checks if the message starts with the prefix and if the message was sent by a bot.

Hope This helped.

```
Happy Coding!
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! I suppose it was important to mention that he is sending those commands from his personal user account (not bot account) so this solution unfortunately doesn't solve the problem :( 
I already implemented this solution following discordjs.guide to prevent my bot from looping.